# Shading problem while creating a heightmap

Tags: shaders, blender-internal-render-engine, height-map

[image]I am trying to create a heightmap from blender GIS addon. I am pretty sure that i have applied correct nodes for creating a heightmap (following a video) but the shading viewport shows only bright white.
[image]

Comment: The way the mesh is rendered depends on the material: what material have you applied to your mesh?

Comment: well that is the problem, i want it to render based on its height. But everything is only white

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lsf6Lihf-YaA61btHyNEr6mcDj5q6DwP/view?usp=sharing
Here is the blend file

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're using an emission shader as a material for your mesh (something I missed when looking at your screenshot).

Since it's emitting light there is no shading on the surface of your mesh, and you won't see the structure properly.

The heightmap was already properly applied to your mesh: the surface is formed according to the height data. But it seems you wanted to apply a gradient to the z-axis, so that the top of the mesh would be white, and the lowest part a solid black.

**In addition to replacing the *Emission* shader with a diffuse one (like a *Principled BSDF*), you need a *Texture Coordinate* node instead of the *Geometry* node you used, and connect the *Separate XYZ* node to its *Generated* socket**, like so:

[image: proper shader setup]

Now your mesh will show up with improved visibility:

[image: resulting render of the mesh]

Note that since your mesh already has the geometry of the heightmap (Mount Fuji), you can use different shaders or image textures.

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem, but I still cannot use the rendered image as heightmap

Comment: @AyushKumar Oh, you want to use this mesh to *create* a heightmap?

Comment: yes, I want to create a heightmap.
Is there any other way of creating a heightmap in blender or may be other in other applications.